# Are there infinitely many primes of the form $2^k-1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This question occurred to me when I hit upon the solutions of the following equation: $\sigma(n)=2n$, where $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of all positive divisors of $n$. Now it can be easily shown that if $2^k-1$ is a prime number then $n=2^{k-1}(2^k-1)$ satisfies the equation. So I decided to search for all values $1\leq k\leq 100$ such that $2^k-1$ is a prime and I obtained the following output:

2 to the power 2= 3 is Prime.

2 to the power 3= 7 is Prime.

2 to the power 5= 31 is Prime.

2 to the power 7= 127 is Prime.

2 to the power 13= 8191 is Prime.

2 to the power 17= 131071 is Prime.

2 to the power 19= 524287 is Prime.

It seems to me that perhaps prime numbers of this form are finite, but I'd like to see otherwise.

Comment: It's unknown whether there are infinitely many Mersenne primes.

Comment: +1 for curiosity. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime and http://www.mersenne.org/

Comment: That is disappointing! Thank you all for your comments...

Comment: Mersenne numbers are interesting because for them there is the [Lucas-Lehmer primality test](https://en.wikipeda.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test#Proof_of_correctness) which is very fast and interesting/not complicated to prove, and it leads to many interesting conjectures and theorems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly easy to show that the exponent has to be a prime (it's not enough though), then primes of that form are called Mersenne primes. As they are easier to test for primality than many other huge numbers, the [Great Internet Mersenne Prime Search](http://www.mersenne.org/) exists to find huge Mersenne primes, and for quite a while has hed the record for the largest known prime, the current record is  $2^{74207281}-1$.

It's unknown whether there are infinitely many, but so far new primes are found regularly, and I think most mathematicians would bet (if you pressured them to, most probably doesn't care) on there being infinitely many.